# Assigning a function to the value of a variable instead of the variable name

Tags: javascript, function, key-bindings

Is it somehow possible to assign this function not to the variable name `shortcut` but to the content of it?

```
if (this.commands[this.counter].shortcut) {
  const shortcut = this.commands[this.counter].shortcut;

  tinykeys(window, {
    shortcut: (event) => {
      this.followLink('https://twitter.com');
    },
  });
}
```

For example: The value of `shortcut` could be a String with value 'abc' and I want to get the following result:

```
tinykeys(window, {
  'abc': (event) => {
    this.followLink('https://twitter.com');
  },
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a computed property name.

```
[shortcut]: (event) => {
   this.followLink('https://twitter.com');
},
```